# How can I simulate a click event On My iPhone4? IOS

Tags: iphone

I want to generate a mouse click event In my iPhone4, how can i implement it?

Answer (score 4):

No way. Since there is no mouse :)

Anyway, you need to send a `sendActionsForControlEvents` message

```
[aResponder sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: thank you ,but I want use a app post TouchInside event to other app, how can i di it?

Comment: well, if the other app is not yours, this is somewhere hacky.